# The asymptotic variance of the mean of a random vector

Tags: gaussian-process, asymptotics

Lets say I have a zero-mean Gaussian random vector X (with dimensions Nx1) with covariance matrix $\Sigma$, where $\Sigma[i,i] = 1, \Sigma[i,j] = r, i\neq j$. 
Also $y$ is the mean of the random vector: i.e. $y = \frac{1^Tx}{N}$. 
Lets define $y_{\infty} = lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{1^Tx}{N}$ be the asymptotic mean, where the dimension of the data vector $X$ goes to infinity.
I am interested in estimating the variance of the asymptotic mean. 
For $r=0$, where the elements are uncorrelated, $Var(y_{\infty})\to \frac{1}{N}$, basically the variance scale inversely with the dimension of the data. I am interested to know if there are any theoretical results for the case $r>0$. How does the variance $y_{\infty}$ scale when the rows of the data are corrected with one-another?

Comment: As the expectation of a sum of some values is the sum of corresponding expectations, then what you need to do is to write down the target variance, transform it and get the answer. Please, identify if you have any problems with this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{Var}\left(\frac 1n \sum X_i\right) = \frac {1}{n^2}n\cdot \text{Var}(X_1)+\frac {1}{n^2}\sum_{i\neq j}\text{Cov}\left(X_i,X_j\right)$$

Per assumptions, $\text{Var}(X_1) = 1, \text{Cov}\left(X_i,X_j\right) = r$ and there are $n^2 - n = n(n-1)$ covariances. So we get

$$\text{Var}\left(\frac 1n \sum X_i\right) = \frac 1n + \frac {n-1}{n}r $$